# "Call to undefined method ..."

Tags: php

I am using the [ReallySimpleJWT](https://github.com/RobDWaller/ReallySimpleJWT) Library and I have changed the server and reinstalled the libraries with Composer again. Only this library gave an error and I don't understand why.

What could be the problem?

> 2022/01/03 22:28:51 [error] 2739#2739: *1635 FastCGI sent in stderr:
> "PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined
> method ReallySimpleJWT\Token::validateExpiration() in
> /var/.......php:23

Line 23:

```
$result = Token::validateExpiration($token, $secretForToken);
```

What could be the cause of this error?

Composer:

```
web2@serve:/var/www/.../panel$ composer require rbdwllr/reallysimplejwt
Using version ^3.1 for rbdwllr/reallysimplejwt
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update rbdwllr/reallysimplejwt
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Package easyframework/collections is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package easyframework/generics is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Generating autoload files
36 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What could be the cause of this error?

The static method your are trying to access on the [`Token`
class](https://github.com/RobDWaller/ReallySimpleJWT/blob/3.x/src/Token.php) does not exist.

Comment: I upgraded the version and it worked. Thank you